# Create a variable and use in various functions in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I create a generic file name and use it in functions in View Controller with following code :

```
 struct MyVariables {

    static var uname = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000000))
    static var shareName = "\(MyVariables.uname).jpg"

}
```

This is working properly in first visit of screen.  But I need to generate another random number each time I visit screen. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it in the `ViewWillAppear` method.

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var uname = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000000))
    static var shareName = "\(MyVariables.uname).jpg"
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    MyVariables.uname = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000000))
    MyVariables.shareName = "\(MyVariables.uname).jpg"

}
```

Comment: @casillas what you need is a read only computed property: static var uname: Int { return  Int(arc4random_uniform(100000000)) }

Comment: and static var shareName: String { return "\\(MyVariables.uname).jpg" }

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you can redefine them again on `viewDidLoad()`.

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var uname = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000000))
    static var shareName = "\(MyVariables.uname).jpg"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyVariables.uname = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000000))
    MyVariables.shareName = "\(MyVariables.uname).jpg"
}
```